# Make my html display full screen wordpress gutenberg

Tags: wordpress

How can I make my page display full screen?  Ideally, removing all WP headers and menus?

I've pasted this into my HTML box in Gutenberg

```
<figure><iframe src="https://cstangor.shinyapps.io/shiny_calendar/" width="100%" height="1000" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make iframe fullscreen. You need to edit your theme templates or add proper css.